# Image processing library/algorithm in c/c++ for contour coordinate detection

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, image-segmentation

Trying to find the contour boundary points of a set of images as a list of x,y coordinates. Here is a set of sample images and I'm looking for the boundaries of the white, gray and the inner blue regions of the donut(cardiac segments). I'm able to get the coordinate of of each color based on levels however, finding the boundary coordinates efficiently is a challenge. Tried convex hull but with limited success. Any advice would be appreciated. Ideally a C++ library that may have a routine to efficiently compute the list. Since,there are lots of such images, efficiency is a key factor.

[image]
    A list of images containing contours of interest.

Comment: Ask at http://dsp.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: I don't see what convex hulls have to do with this. What you are looking for is boundary tracing (or contour tracing). There are numerous resources on the net about it.

Comment: Could you use edge detection to generate a list of edge pixels that need checking as to which edge they are on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) is a good image processing library with lots of features including [findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours). There is a also a GPU support but i dont think for the `findContours` algorithm. But its free and easy to implement. Maybe the performance is still good enough.